# How to post a tweet to the specific follower using the screen name in ios 5 and greater

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a table view which shows my twitter followers list. I like to send the tweet to the specific follower only. After selecting the row i will get a screen name and id of the follower and how can i post a tweet using only follower name in this method

[postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount]

Is there any other way other than using this method.

thank you in advance.